# Delivering and using an Azure REST-API SharedKey for Blob Upload

Tags: rest, azure, azure-storage

We currently use the REST API (based on microsoft samples) to upload blobs blockwise from a .NET client profile machine. The REST API examples use the Azure storage account name and access key directly to construct the SharedKey entry in the request header. For production code, we'll need to calculate the SharedKey on our server, and deliver it for the client to use during the session.

Examples of SharedKey creation for blobs provide me with a Url plus query string that contains the access parameters.

My question: How do I get this Url/query string key format work in conjunction with the SharedKey header entry required by the Azure REST API?

Any pointers or tips greatly appreciated!
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Obviously a lot of improvement can be made to this code :) Give it a try. Do let me know if it works for you. I was able to upload a blob in development storage using the code below:


`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Globalization;`

namespace UploadBlobUsingSASUrl
{
    class Program
    {
        //This is part of SAS signature (query string). We will construct the URI later using this.
        private static string sasSignature = "sr=c&st=2012-08-16T14%3A38%3A48Z&se=2012-08-16T15%3A38%3A48Z&sp=w&sig=aNTLYQtwA1UmjG7j8Lg44t8YThL16FkNYBi54kl4ZKo%3D";
        //Blob storage endpoint
        private static string blobStorageEndpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1";
        //Blob container name
        private static string blobContainerName = "[blob container name. SAS URI with Write permission must be created on this blob container]";
        //File to upload
        private static string fileToUpload = @"[Full path of the file you wish to upload]";
        //This is the default block size (This application always assumes that a file will be split in blocks and then uploaded).
        private static int blockSize = 256 * 1024;//256 KB
        //Storage service version (Unless you're using latest SAS related changes in cloud storage, use this version). For development storage always use this version.
        private static string x_ms_version = "2011-08-18";
        //Template for put block list
        private static string blockListTemplate = @"{0}";
        // Template for block id (to be included in put block list template)
        private static string blockIdTemplate = "{0}";
        //We'll keep a list of block ids.
        private static List blockIds = new List();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileToUpload);
        long totalFileSize = file.Length;//Get the file size
        long bytesFrom = 0;
        long bytesRemaining = totalFileSize;
        string blobName = file.Name;
        //This is the base URI which will be used for put blocks and put block list operations.
        //It is essentially would be something like "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/myblobcontainer/myblobname?sassignature"
        string baseUri = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}?{3}", blobStorageEndpoint, blobContainerName, blobName, sasSignature);
        int counter = 0;
        //In this loop, we'll read file in chunks and try and upload one chunk at a time.
        while (true)
        {
            int bytesToRead = blockSize;
            if (bytesRemaining < blockSize)
            {
                bytesToRead = (int)bytesRemaining;
            }
            //Read the file in chunks
            byte[] fileContents = ReadFile(fileToUpload, bytesFrom, bytesToRead);
            bytesRemaining -= fileContents.Length;
            bytesFrom += fileContents.Length;
            //Create block id
            string blockId = string.Format("Block-{0:D5}", counter);
            //Append that to the block id list.
            blockIds.Add(blockId);
            //Now let's upload the block.
            var isBlockUploaded = UploadBlock(baseUri, fileContents, blockId);
            Console.WriteLine("Block Id: " + blockId + " Block Size: " + fileContents.Length + " Uploaded: " + isBlockUploaded);
            counter++;
            if (bytesRemaining <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        //All blocks uploaded, now let's commit the block list
        var isBlockListCommitted = CommitBlockList(baseUri, blockIds);
        Console.WriteLine("Is Block List Committed: " + isBlockListCommitted);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate the program ....");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function reads a chunk of the file and returns that as byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <param name="bytesFrom"></param>
    /// <param name="bytesToRead"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static byte[] ReadFile(string fileName, long bytesFrom, int bytesToRead)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[bytesToRead];
            fs.Seek(bytesFrom, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            fs.Read(byteArray, 0, bytesToRead);
            return byteArray;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function uploads a block.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="baseUri"></param>
    /// <param name="blockContents"></param>
    /// <param name="blockId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool UploadBlock(string baseUri, byte[] blockContents, string blockId)
    {
        bool isBlockUploaded = false;
        //Create request URI - 
        string uploadBlockUri = string.Format("{0}&comp=block&blockId={1}", baseUri, Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId)));
        // Create request object
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(uploadBlockUri);
        NameValueCollection requestHeaders = new NameValueCollection();
        var requestDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        //Add request headers. Please note that since we're using SAS URI, we don't really need "Authorization" header.
        requestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:R}", requestDate));
        requestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", x_ms_version);
        request.Headers.Add(requestHeaders);
        //Set content length header.
        request.ContentLength = blockContents.Length;
        //Set request HTTP method.
        request.Method = "PUT";

        // Send the request
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(blockContents, 0, blockContents.Length);
        }
        // Get the response
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            isBlockUploaded = response.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
        return isBlockUploaded;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function commits the block list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="baseUri"></param>
    /// <param name="blockIds"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool CommitBlockList(string baseUri, List<string> blockIds)
    {
        bool isBlockListCommitted = false;
        //Create the request payload
        StringBuilder blockIdsPayload = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var blockId in blockIds)
        {
            blockIdsPayload.AppendFormat(blockIdTemplate, Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId)));
        }
        string putBlockListPayload = string.Format(blockListTemplate, blockIdsPayload.ToString());
        // Create request URI
        string putBlockListUrl = string.Format("{0}&comp=blocklist", baseUri);
        // Create request object.
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(putBlockListUrl);
        NameValueCollection requestHeaders = new NameValueCollection();
        //Add request headers. Please note that since we're using SAS URI, we don't really need "Authorization" header.
        var requestDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        requestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:R}", requestDate));
        requestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", x_ms_version);
        byte[] requestPayload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(putBlockListPayload);
        //Set content length header.
        request.ContentLength = requestPayload.Length;
        request.Headers.Add(requestHeaders);
        //Set request HTTP method.
        request.Method = "PUT";

        // Send the request
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(requestPayload, 0, requestPayload.Length);
        }

        // Get the response
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            isBlockListCommitted = response.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
        return isBlockListCommitted;


    }
}

}

Comment: Thanks Guarav! Great, this looks similar to my blockwise upload code except that you confirm that we can leave off the SharedKey request header. I tried that, but got a "bad request" message back, so I must have had something else awry. Also, apparently the PUT block size does not have to be part of the key calc, as it is in the REST API. I'll let you know. In any case, I owe you one (and owe stackeoverflow one). R

Comment: Can you share your code so that it can get looked at? My guess is that either you're missing one of the request headers or there might be an issue with SAS generation.

Comment: I'll post code when done -- or if I can't get it working :-) Thanks again! R

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to generate Shared Access Signature (SAS) URL. Am I correct? When you generate the SAS URLs, the permissions are encoded in the URI itself so that you don't have to use the authorization key anymore.

For generating SAS, you may find these two links useful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh508996

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I've already done that, it looks like this: 

http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/products-wawi-blob-uploads/5126d6a2-941d-4c17-a8x1-caf411cb13t2?st=2012-08-16T08:40:07Z&se=2012-08-16T09:20:07Z&sr=c&sp=rw&sig=5CXKziA+xBxP5FT52N/OIIvuRWtSl0d/OPTpTHqPIiI=

and it is returned to my client. My client must use the REST Api, which, currently, creates its own SharedKey entry in the request header. Are you saying that I do not have to have this entry in the request header anymore? When I read the REST API doc, it appears that it is required...

Comment: I don't think you can use SAS URL with REST API. What you could do however is use simple WebRequest/WebResponse and use SAS URI as your request URL. Take a look at this blog post which shows how you can upload a file using SAS URI: http://wely-lau.net/2012/01/10/uploading-file-securely-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-with-shared-access-signature-via-rest-api/

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, Nice try :-) but won't work for us since we are using the PutBlock incremental uploads of large datafiles where a single PUT won't handle the load. Also, there must be a direct sematic link between the two: I see lots of commonality, I'm just fighting format and syntax here, I think. Or maybe I can generate the SharedKey Header for the Rest API on the server? Problem there: the current sample impl. uses the blob size in the "StringToSign" and I don't know the blob size if I'm generating the shared access key on the server. Anybody with an idea here? Thanks!

Comment: Let me scratch my previous comment. Sorry!!! It is indeed possible to use REST API with SAS signature. I just created a sample console application which does just that. Let me add that as an answer in a bit (Need to add some comments in my code and will post it here)

Comment: cool. saves the day! thanks again. I hope I can calc and load the SharedKey from the server so the .NET client profile can use it with my blockwise upload (PutBlock)...

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure what you mean when you say "SharedKey." If you're using SAS, you just tack the signature on to the end of the URL, as a set of query string parameters. Here's some code that uses the Put Block API with SAS (in Silverlight): http://blog.smarx.com/posts/uploading-windows-azure-blobs-from-silverlight-part-3-handling-big-files-by-using-the-block-apis

Answer (score 0):

Here is my resulting code (minus some cleanup to do) as successfully tested in the emulation environment. First, the client-side code, which are adapted methods from the Microsoft REST API examples, BlobHelper.cs. Then the server-side code that delivers the Endpoint URL used by the client code. Thanks again for the tips! R

```
//
// Client side: The "Endpoint" used below is the Uri as returned from the Server-side  code below.
//
//
    public bool PutBlock(int blockId, string[] blockIds, byte[] value)
    {
        return Retry<bool>(delegate()
        {
            HttpWebResponse response;

            try
            {
                SortedList<string, string> headers = new SortedList<string, string>();

                byte[] blockIdBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(blockId);
                string blockIdBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(blockIdBytes);

                blockIds[blockId] = blockIdBase64;

                // SharedAccessKey version.
                //End result will look similar to this in Fiddler if correct:
                //PUT http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/uploads/aecdfa39-7eaa-474a-9333-ecf43e6a0508?st=2012-08-17T16%3A11%3A53Z&se=2012-08-17T16%3A51%3A53Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sig=2%2Fs0R1L78S55pW5o2WontVvlZypjkTriWoljnycPbFc%3D&comp=block&blockid=AAAAAA== HTTP/1.1
                //
                response = CreateRESTRequestDirectUtf8("PUT", "&comp=block&blockid=" + blockIdBase64, value, headers).GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                response.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError &&
                    ex.Response != null &&
                    (int)((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode == 409) 
                    return false;

                throw;
            }
        });
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Put block list - complete creation of blob based on uploaded content.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">The container.</param>
    /// <param name="blob">The BLOB.</param>
    /// <param name="blockIds">The block ids.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool PutBlockList(string[] blockIds)
    {
        return Retry<bool>(delegate()
        {
            HttpWebResponse response;

            try
            {
                StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
                content.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
                content.Append("<BlockList>");
                for (int i = 0; i < blockIds.Length; i++)
                {
                    content.Append("<Latest>" + blockIds[i] + "</Latest>");
                }
                content.Append("</BlockList>");
                response = CreateRESTRequest("PUT", "&comp=blocklist", content.ToString(), null).GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                response.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError &&
                    ex.Response != null &&
                    (int)(ex.Response as HttpWebResponse).StatusCode == 409)
                    return false;

                throw;
            }
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Construct and issue a REST request and return the response.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="method">The method.</param>
    /// <param name="resource">The resource.</param>
    /// <param name="requestBody">The request body.</param>
    /// <param name="headers">The headers.</param>
    /// <param name="ifMatch">If match.</param>
    /// <param name="md5">The MD5.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public HttpWebRequest CreateRESTRequest(string method, string resource, string requestBody = null, SortedList<string, string> headers = null,
        string ifMatch = "", string md5 = "")
    {
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Uri uri = new Uri(Endpoint + resource);

        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now.ToString("R", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2009-09-19"); //2009-09-19, 2011-08-18

        if (IsTableStorage)
        {
            request.ContentType = "application/atom+xml";

            request.Headers.Add("DataServiceVersion", "1.0;NetFx");
            request.Headers.Add("MaxDataServiceVersion", "1.0;NetFx");
        }

        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> header in headers)
            {
                request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

            byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        }

        // We now get our SharedAccessKey from the server
        //request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader(method, now, request, ifMatch, md5));

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
        {
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
        return request;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the REST request direct UTF8.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="method">The method.</param>
    /// <param name="resource">The resource.</param>
    /// <param name="requestBodyUtf8">The request body UTF8.</param>
    /// <param name="headers">The headers.</param>
    /// <param name="ifMatch">If match.</param>
    /// <param name="md5">The MD5.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private HttpWebRequest CreateRESTRequestDirectUtf8(string method, string resource, byte[] requestBodyUtf8, SortedList<string, string> headers = null, string ifMatch = "", string md5 = "")
    {
        //byte[] byteArray = null;
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Uri uri = new Uri(Endpoint + resource);

        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now.ToString("R", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2009-09-19"); //2009-09-19, 2011-08-18

        if (IsTableStorage)
        {
            request.ContentType = "application/atom+xml";

            request.Headers.Add("DataServiceVersion", "1.0;NetFx");
            request.Headers.Add("MaxDataServiceVersion", "1.0;NetFx");
        }

        // Additional headers can be passed in as a formal parameter:
        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> header in headers)
            {
                request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
        }

        if (requestBodyUtf8 != null)
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            request.ContentLength = requestBodyUtf8.Length;
        }

        // We now get our SharedAccessKey from the server 
        //request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader(method, now, request, ifMatch, md5));

        if (requestBodyUtf8 != null)
        {
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(requestBodyUtf8, 0, requestBodyUtf8.Length);
        }

        return request;
    }

    //
    // Server side: The returned Uri here is the "Endpoint" used in the client code.
    //
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the blob-level shared access signature for the named blob
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="blobName">The unique blob name Guid.</param>
    /// <returns>The fully qualified Azure Shared Access Signature Query String to be used in azure upload connections</returns>
    public Uri GetBlobUploadUrl(Guid blobName)
    {
        string containerName = BlobContainerName;
        const string permissions = "rw";
        string sharedAccessSignature = CreateSharedAccessSignature(containerName, blobName.ToString(), permissions);

        string urlPath;
        if (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated)
        { // Emulation environment
          urlPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}{3}", _blobEndpoint, containerName, blobName, sharedAccessSignature);               
        }
        else
        { // Cloud
            urlPath = String.Format("{0}{1}/{2}{3}", _blobEndpoint, containerName, blobName, sharedAccessSignature);
        }

        Uri uri = new Uri(urlPath);

        return uri;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a blob-level shared access signature.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="containerName">The blob container name.</param>
    /// <param name="blobName">The blob name, a unique ID which will be passed back to the client.</param>
    /// <param name="permissions">String of access levels, "r" = read, "w" = write "rw" = both etc.</param>
    /// <returns>The fully qualified Azure Shared Access Signature Query String</returns>
    private string CreateSharedAccessSignature(string containerName, string blobName, string permissions)
    {
        // SAS without stored container policy
        const string iso8061Format = "{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ}";
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-10d); //UtcNow;
        DateTime expiryTime = startTime.AddMinutes(40d);
        string start = string.Format(iso8061Format, startTime);
        string expiry = string.Format(iso8061Format, expiryTime);
        string stringToSign = string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n/{3}/{4}/{5}\n", permissions, start, expiry, _accountName, containerName, blobName);

        // SAS with stored container policy
        //string stringToSign = String.Format("\n\n\n/{0}/{1}\n{2}", accountName, containerName, policyId);

        string rawSignature = String.Empty;
        Byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(_accountKey); 
        using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
        {
            Byte[] utf8EncodedStringToSign = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
            Byte[] signatureBytes = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(utf8EncodedStringToSign);
            rawSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
        }

        string sharedAccessSignature = String.Format("?st={0}&se={1}&sr=b&sp={2}&sig={3}", Uri.EscapeDataString(start), Uri.EscapeDataString(expiry), permissions, Uri.EscapeDataString(rawSignature));
        //
        // End result will look like this in Fiddler if correct:
        //PUT http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/uploads/aecdfa39-7eaa-474a-9333-ecf43e6a0508?st=2012-08-17T16%3A11%3A53Z&se=2012-08-17T16%3A51%3A53Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sig=2%2Fs0R1L78S55uW5o2WontVvrZypckTriWoijnyrPbFc%3D&comp=block&blockid=AAAAAA== HTTP/1.1
        //
        return sharedAccessSignature;
    }
```